# Questionário para cadeira de TCC

Tags: debate

Pessoal queria saber se tem algum lugar para pessoas postarem questionário de opinião para pesquisa de campo de TCC, preciso para compor minha pesquisa...

se alguém puder ajudar segue o link>>>>

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1CqM6qbBtluzzNP9nThVvGmeEBZsTxec_LmgXcEuBRW0/viewform

Basicamente são perguntas sobre o processo de qualidade em empresas de TI..

Grato...

Comment: O espaço que pode divulgar sua pesquisa no [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha), está acessivel pelo menu no canto esquerdo da tela.